# Domain restrictions and interval of validity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$
ty'(t)-y(t)=t^2, \quad y(1)=0.
$$
Using, for example, integrating factor to solve this ODE would require dividing by $t$ first, and hence imposing domain restrictions on the solution (say $t>0$). However, if we solve the equation we find that $$
y(t)=t^2-t,
$$
which is valid for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and satisfies the equation at $t=0$. That being said, should I still restrict the domain on which the solution $y(t)$ to the IVP is valid to $t>0$, or given that nothing is getting undefined I can consider it to be valid on the whole real line (even though the method that I used required dividing by zero in the first place)? Is there any (maybe for a different ODE) counterexample where the solution obtained by integrating factor is well-defined (and solves the ODE) for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, but somehow the solution has some problem at the discontinuity points of the coefficients? Does anyone have a good/"complete" explanation of how to interpret this situation when the coefficients are discontinuous but the solution is somehow continuous, differentiable, and solves the ODE for all times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence and uniqueness theorem for first-order linear differential equations says: If $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ re continuous in the open interval $(a,b)$, than the Initial Value Problem (IVP) $y'+p(t)y=q(t)$ with $y(t_0)=y_0$, where $t_0 \in (a,b)$, has a unique solution in $(a,b)$.

So to understand better the situation when the coefficients are discontinuous, you negate the conclusion of the theorem, that is: or there will be no solution to the IVP or there will be infinitely many.

As an example let's take the IVP, with your original ODE, $ty'-y=t^2$ with $y(0)=y_0$. Note that, be using the [Integrating Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor), the general solution to the ODE is
$$y=t^2+Ct$$
and, in this case, we have $y(0)=0$ for all $C$. That is: if $y_0=0$ than the IVP has infinitely many solutions (take any $C$). If $y_0 \neq0$ than the IVP has no solution.

As an second example, consider the slightly different IVP $t^2y-y= \frac{1}{t}$ with $y(0)=y_0$. The general solution to the ODE is
$$y=\frac{t-1}{t}+Ce^{-\frac{1}{t}}.$$
In this case, there's no solution for any $y_0$.

This illustrate the general case (even for high order linear ODE's): We have non unique solutions for some $y_0$ or no solution at all. What dictates this is if your point (in this case $t_0=0$) is an [Regular Singular Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) (the exponents at the singularity play a important role) or an Irregular one.